# phpThumb to return HTTP error instead of ugly error image

Tags: php, cdn, phpthumb

We are using phpThumb to resize images, create thumbnails from the original version stored in a DB

We are using a CDN so that thumbnails are cached and we only pay the image processing once per image and per different size.

This works pretty well. Our only issue is that when occasionally there is a temporary glitch phpthumb will produce a custom image with an error message.

This error image will get cached by the CDN as a normal image which means subsequent users will also see the error image.

Is there a way to configure phpThumb so that it returns a HTTP error message when there is a problem instead of showing this error image?

Then at least problems would not persist due to caching since the CDN would "know" not to store the error image but retry later.

thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have't used phpthumb, but if you want a qucik solution, delete the placeholderimage .

Comment: thanks! that worked. phpthumb redirects to the configured custom error image and this produces a 404 error.